# How to Include related objects in view using ADO.net

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net-mvc, linq, ado.net

I'm using C# and ASP.NET MVC. Usually I also use Entity Framework but recently I've been using ADO.net and SQL. I have a problem with my ADO.NET code: in Entity Framework/LINQ to solve the problem I'd use the `Include` keyword to include related data into the view so I don't get an object not reference error so the question is how to I do that using ADO.NET what would be the equivalent of the LINQ `Include` keyword in ADO.NET and SQL?

Code example of the `Include` keyword:

```
private Comment GetComment(int? id)       
{
     return id.HasValue ? Db.Comments.Where(x=> x.ID == id)
                                     .Include(y => y.Replies)
                                     .First() : new Comment { ID = -1 };
}
```

As you can see from the Comments I'm also loading the Replies from another table they are related.

How do I do this in ADO.Net and SQL?

Comment: You need to `JOIN` the two tables in your SQL statement ....

Comment: I've joined , problem is how to pass the joined data to the Model correctly e.g i have comments and comments has a list of replies in its model , the view is of type comments how do i pass the replies to the comment model ?? just think about it carefully , in the comment Model i'll have a list of object of replies , when data comes from the reader and i loop through it i can easily populate the Comments  but can't populate the replies because i cant pass replies data to an object of reply type only normal fields i can pass data to.

Comment: You'll need a combined "viewmodel" of sorts that can hold all the data being returned from the joined query

Comment: You're basically executing raw SQL queries, so you have to do all of the object creation. That's why ORMs exist. Why use ADO.Net?

Answer (score 0):

I think problem is that my experience with include means entity.

So in your case:

```
Db.Comments.Where(x => x.ID == id)
           .Include("Replies")
           .First() : new Comment { ID = -1 };
```

and **IN** your data model should be the relation:

```
public class Comments
{
    private readonly ObservableListSource<Replies> _replies =
                       new ObservableListSource<Replies>();
    
    public int ID { get; set; }
    // (other attributes)
    
    public virtual ObservableListSource<Replies> Replies
    { get { return replies; } }
}
```